# Как установить OpenGL на Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, g++

Здравствуйте, подскажите как установить OpenGL? Компилятор g++

Comment: Из http://singhgurjot.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/how-to-install-openglglut-libraries-in-ubuntu-12-04/

       sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev

Правда там ещё пишут про binutils-gold, но тут я не знаю, у меня тест собрался и без него. Правда в комманда для сборки test странная

       gcc -lGL -lglut test.c -o test

д.б. наоборот, библиотеки после test.c

       g++ test.c -o test -lGL -lglut

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как установить OpenGL на Ubuntu?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613894/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-opengl-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поставь себе с помощью программы Synaptic такие либы:

- freeglut3
- freeglut3-dev
- libglew1.5
- libglew1.5-dev
- libglu1-mesa
- libglu1-mesa-dev
- libgl1-mesa-glx
- libgl1-mesa-dev

Потом для компиляции кода в Линуксе  будешь использовать g++ example.cpp -o example -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW

Comment: @Qnex /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLEW
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1