# Как установить OpenGL на Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, c, кодировка, opengl, компиляция

Как установить OpenGL? Компилятор gсс.
Все библиотеки установлены:

```
freeglut3
freeglut3-dev
libglew1.5
libglew1.5-dev
libglu1-mesa
libglu1-mesa-dev
libgl1-mesa-glx
libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Не работает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
void display(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     // Очистка экрана
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
 gluOrtho2D(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
 glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
 glVertex2f(0.0,0.0);
 glVertex2f(1.0,0.0);
 glVertex2f(0.0,1.0);
 glVertex2f(1.0,1.0);
 glVertex2f(0.0,-1.0);
 glVertex2f(-1.0,0.0);
  glVertex2f(-1.0,-1.0);
 glEnd();
glFlush();
     }
extern int main(int arg,char** arc){
    glutInit(arg,&arc);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow("Simp");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    //glutMouseFunc(mouse);//координаты мыши функция
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки при компиляции:

```
gcc -Wall -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW-c "main.c" (в каталоге: /home/Рабочий стол)
In file included from main.c:27:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:85:2: error: #error gl.h included before glew.h
 #error gl.h included before glew.h
  ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:97:2: error: #error glext.h included before glew.h
 #error glext.h included before glew.h
  ^
In file included from main.c:27:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15755:28: error: conflicting types for ‘PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC’
 typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum pname, GLfloat* params);
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:128,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from main.c:24:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:11529:25: note: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC’ was here
 typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum pname, const GLfloat *params);
                         ^
In file included from main.c:27:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15757:28: error: conflicting types for ‘PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC’
 typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum pname, GLint* params);
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:128,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from main.c:24:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:11531:25: note: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC’ was here
 typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum pname, const GLint *params);
                         ^
In file included from main.c:27:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15759:28: error: conflicting types for ‘PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC’
 typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum light, GLenum pname, GLfloat* params);
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:128,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from main.c:24:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:11525:25: note: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC’ was here
 typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum light, GLenum pname, const GLfloat *params);
                         ^
In file included from main.c:27:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15761:28: error: conflicting types for ‘PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTIVSGIXPROC’
 typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum light, GLenum pname, GLint* params);
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:128,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from main.c:24:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:11527:25: note: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTIVSGIXPROC’ was here
 typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum light, GLenum pname, const GLint *params);
                         ^
In file included from main.c:27:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15768:28: error: conflicting types for ‘PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALFVSGIXPROC’
 typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum face, GLenum pname, const GLfloat* data);
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:128,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from main.c:24:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:11538:25: note: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALFVSGIXPROC’ was here
 typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum face, GLenum pname, GLfloat *params);
                         ^
In file included from main.c:27:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15769:28: error: conflicting types for ‘PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALIVSGIXPROC’
 typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum face, GLenum pname, const GLint* data);
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:128,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from main.c:24:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:11539:25: note: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALIVSGIXPROC’ was here
 typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum face, GLenum pname, GLint *params);
                         ^
In file included from main.c:27:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16432:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCLIENTACTIVETEXTUREPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCLIENTACTIVETEXTUREPROC __glewClientActiveTexture;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16440:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC __glewLoadTransposeMatrixd;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16441:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC __glewLoadTransposeMatrixf;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16442:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC __glewMultTransposeMatrixd;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16443:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC __glewMultTransposeMatrixf;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16444:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1d;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16445:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1dv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16446:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1f;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16447:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1fv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16448:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1i;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16449:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1iv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16450:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1s;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16451:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1sv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16452:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2d;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16453:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2dv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16454:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2f;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16455:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2fv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16456:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2IPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2IPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2i;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16457:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2IVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2IVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2iv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16458:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2SPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2SPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2s;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16459:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2SVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2SVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2sv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16460:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3DPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3DPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3d;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16461:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3DVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3DVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3dv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16462:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3FPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3FPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3f;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16463:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3FVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3FVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3fv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16464:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3IPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3IPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3i;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16465:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3IVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3IVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3iv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16466:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3SPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3SPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3s;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16467:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3SVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3SVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3sv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16468:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4DPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4DPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4d;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16469:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4DVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4DVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4dv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16470:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4FPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4FPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4f;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16471:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4FVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4FVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4fv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16472:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4IPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4IPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4i;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16473:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4IVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4IVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4iv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16474:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4SPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4SPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4s;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16475:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4SVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4SVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4sv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17106:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCOLORSUBTABLEPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOLORSUBTABLEPROC __glewColorSubTable;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17107:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCOLORTABLEPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOLORTABLEPROC __glewColorTable;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17108:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVPROC __glewColorTableParameterfv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17109:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVPROC __glewColorTableParameteriv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17110:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DPROC __glewConvolutionFilter1D;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17111:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DPROC __glewConvolutionFilter2D;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17112:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFPROC __glewConvolutionParameterf;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17113:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVPROC __glewConvolutionParameterfv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17114:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIPROC __glewConvolutionParameteri;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17115:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVPROC __glewConvolutionParameteriv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17116:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCOPYCOLORSUBTABLEPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOPYCOLORSUBTABLEPROC __glewCopyColorSubTable;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17117:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCOPYCOLORTABLEPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOPYCOLORTABLEPROC __glewCopyColorTable;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17118:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DPROC __glewCopyConvolutionFilter1D;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17119:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DPROC __glewCopyConvolutionFilter2D;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17120:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPROC __glewGetColorTable;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17121:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVPROC __glewGetColorTableParameterfv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17122:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVPROC __glewGetColorTableParameteriv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17123:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONFILTERPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONFILTERPROC __glewGetConvolutionFilter;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17124:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVPROC __glewGetConvolutionParameterfv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17125:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVPROC __glewGetConvolutionParameteriv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17126:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPROC __glewGetHistogram;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17127:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERFVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERFVPROC __glewGetHistogramParameterfv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17128:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERIVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERIVPROC __glewGetHistogramParameteriv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17129:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETMINMAXPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETMINMAXPROC __glewGetMinmax;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17130:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETMINMAXPARAMETERFVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETMINMAXPARAMETERFVPROC __glewGetMinmaxParameterfv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17131:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETMINMAXPARAMETERIVPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETMINMAXPARAMETERIVPROC __glewGetMinmaxParameteriv;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17132:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLGETSEPARABLEFILTERPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETSEPARABLEFILTERPROC __glewGetSeparableFilter;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17133:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLHISTOGRAMPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLHISTOGRAMPROC __glewHistogram;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17134:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLMINMAXPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMINMAXPROC __glewMinmax;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17135:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLRESETHISTOGRAMPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLRESETHISTOGRAMPROC __glewResetHistogram;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17136:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLRESETMINMAXPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLRESETMINMAXPROC __glewResetMinmax;
                 ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17137:17: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLSEPARABLEFILTER2DPROC’
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLSEPARABLEFILTER2DPROC __glewSeparableFilter2D;
                 ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:47:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘glutInit’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  glutInit(arg,&arc);
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17:0,
                 from main.c:24:
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:398:26: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 FGAPI void    FGAPIENTRY glutInit( int* pargc, char** argv );
                          ^
main.c:47:15: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘glutInit’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  glutInit(arg,&arc);
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17:0,
                 from main.c:24:
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:398:26: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char ***’
 FGAPI void    FGAPIENTRY glutInit( int* pargc, char** argv );
                          ^
Сборка завершилась с ошибкой.
```

Comment: Вы вообще читаете, что вам компилятор пишет, или это так, тактика, и не стратегу этим заниматься? :)

Comment: так помогите разобраться ;)

Comment: в С++ такой код будет работать, а в Си не работает магия

Comment: *в каталоге: /home/Рабочий стол* — просто добрая рекомендация из небольших запасов опыта: не используйте спец-символы (типа пробела) и, тем более, не-ascii символы в именах каталогов (включая все, начиная с корня), где занимаетесь сборкой.

Comment: `opengl`  поставляется с драйверами от видеокарты, вобще говоря, а то, что вы пытаетесь подключить называются вспомогательные необходимые библиотеки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет. там вверху пишет немного ошибок что не включены две либы:

```
#error gl.h included before glew.h
#error glext.h included before glew.h
```

Попробуйте сделать так в инклудах

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
...
```

Но там дальше ошибка:

```
error: unknown type name ‘GLenum’
```

Чего то еще не доставлено видать

**P.S.**
Попробуйте такой код скомпилить:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
void display(void){
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     // Очистка экрана
     glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
     gluOrtho2D(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
     glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
     glVertex2f(0.0,0.0);
     glVertex2f(1.0,0.0);
     glVertex2f(0.0,1.0);
     glVertex2f(1.0,1.0);
     glVertex2f(0.0,-1.0);
     glVertex2f(-1.0,0.0);
     glVertex2f(-1.0,-1.0);
     glEnd();
     glFlush();
}
extern int main(int arg,char** arc){
    glutInit(&arg,arc);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow("Simp");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    //glutMouseFunc(mouse);//координаты мыши функция
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не работает ошибки теже. Может библиотеки какой нибудь  библиотеки не хватает. Те библиотеки freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglew1.5 libglew1.5-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev С++ные наверное.

Comment: Странно этих ошибок быть не должно:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:85:2: error: #error gl.h included before glew.h
 #error gl.h included before glew.h
  ^
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:97:2: error: #error glext.h included before glew.h
 #error glext.h included before glew.h

Comment: Библиотеки установлены но работают неправильно.

Comment: Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  23
  Current serial number in output stream:  24

Comment: это glxgears ^^^

Comment: код получилось скомпилить?

Comment: Нет. Убил систему Ubuntu  сечас на Puppy Linux покапаюсь

Comment: ну не как не компилируется странно...

Comment: Антон, еще раз проверил все на чистой системе код который в ответе у меня, на чистом дебиане с установкой тех библиотек которые вы указали плюс build-essential строкой gcc -Wall -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -c "main.c" скомпилился без ошибок и создал main.o

Comment: Ккомпилируется но не собирается в исполняемый файл 
/tmp/ccvQDhx3.o: In function `display':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `glClear'
main.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Сборка завершилась с ошибкой.